# how to call ashx file using ajax in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I m developing website. i want call one ashx file which return all process list on server

Comment: What did you try? At which point did you get stuck? (call an url, call an ashx, create an ashx, list all processes, return that list, display that list, ..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step: 1 Create the handler and the server side code like the following

<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        var processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(processes.Select(p => p.ProcessName)));


    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Step 2: Give the necessary permissions for your asp.net process / application pool. In development version you can add the impersonation tag in the web.config as a shortcut.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="windows/usernamer" password="password"/>
```

Step 3:
Use the handler's result from the aspx page via ajax or otherwise. An example is as follows using the jquery library.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="CS" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">

</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <ul id="processes">

    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.get("handler.ashx", function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                    $("#processes").append($("<li />").html(element));
                });
            });
        });    
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much it is so helpful to me